# Align tex with heigh of icon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap 5

[image]

Instead of having text below icon, I would like text align verticaly with icon heigh

```css
h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.testHead {
  background-color: #5c636a;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.testHead .col {
  font-size: 1.2rem!important;
}

.testHead i {
  font-size: 4rem!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="testHead">
  <h3>For a few dollar</h3>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col ">
      <i class="bi bi-display"></i> Answer simple question

    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <i class="bi bi-download"></i> Download and print
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <i class="bi bi-clock"></i> It take less then 10 minutes
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Search to get something like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your elements flex, it's the easiest solution.
Add these Bootstrap classes to your elements that need to be vertically centered like this :

```
 <nav class="testHead">
  <h3>For a few dollar</h3>
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col d-flex align-items-center">
      <i class="bi bi-display"></i>
      Answer simple question
    </div>
    <div class="col d-flex align-items-center">
      <i class="bi bi-download"></i>
      Download and print
    </div>
    <div class="col d-flex align-items-center">
      <i class="bi bi-clock"></i>
      It take less then 10 minutes
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

or with simple CSS.

Surround your texts with a p tag, with a classname to give the margin-letf

Ex :

```
  <div class="col d-flex align-items-center">
      <i class="bi bi-display"></i>
      <p class="descr">Answer simple question</p>
   </div>
```

and then apply css to your  `<div class="col">` :

```
.col {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.col .descr {
  margin-left: 10px
}
```